# How to do inverse_transform in OneHotEncoder and LabelEncoder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I checked that `OneHotEncoder` does not have an `inverse_transform()` method. How to get the values ​​back by reversing the transformation?

Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer


base = pd.read_csv(caminho + "risco_credito.csv")

previsores = base.loc[:,["historia","divida","garantias","renda"]].values

classe = base.loc[:,"risco"].values


labelencorder_classe = LabelEncoder()
classe_enc = labelencorder_classe.fit_transform(classe)


onehotencorder = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("OneHot", OneHotEncoder(), [0,1,2,3])],remainder='passthrough')

previsores_enc = onehotencorder.fit_transform(previsores)
```

For example: `Classe_enc` and `previsores_enc` , how to do the inverse transformation, that is, get the values ​​back by reversing the transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are referring to a wrong documentation. The `inverse_transform` is available for `OneHotEncoder` and `ordinalEncoder`.

See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.inverse_transform)

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
>>> x = np.random.choice(['orange','apple', 'mango'],size=(3,1))
>>> ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("OneHot", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), [0])],
                           remainder='passthrough')

>>> x_trans_ = ct.fit_transform(x)
>>> ct.named_transformers_['OneHot'].inverse_transform(x_trans_)
array([['orange'],
       ['orange'],
       ['apple']], dtype='<U6')
```

Similarly, you can do it for `ordinalEncoder`, refer [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.inverse_transform)

Comment: I tried to use inverse_transform in my example but I got ColumnTransformer has not inverse_transform. What happened?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the argmax function from numpy to get the index of the array element with the maximum value (this will be the index of the element that is 1 since the other values should be 0). Then you could use a dictionary to associate this index with a class label if necessary.